# Add flow expression to update item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

Based on the workflow expression created below, how can I can add/integrate it with `update item` in a `SharePoint` website?

Purpose: I would like to tell the SharePoint website that whenever a new row (every time `add new item` is clicked in edit grid view) is added, auto generate the next column (Reference Number (datatype `numeric`) value based on the previous value which for example is `10321`.

reference_number column in `descending` order:

[image]

For example, let's say the last `reference_number` value is `10132` then, whenever the user clicks on add new item SharePoint should autogenerate the next `reference_number` which in this case would be `10133`. Thus, each time  `add new item` is clicked, the reference_number will be autogenerated by adding `1` to `previous/last` value.

How can I setup `update item`?

Error:

Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Initialize_variable' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'add' expects its first parameter to be an integer, a float or a decimal number. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#add for usage details.'.

Expression:

```
add(triggerOutputs()?['body/reference_number'], 1)
```

Current workflow:

[image]

Updated workflow:

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error while using this expression? Or are you unable to add the expression?

Comment: Yes let me edit my question to add more details.

Comment: I think you are passing Null value to `add` function. Are you entering any value in "Reference Number" while saving list form OR you are trying to read the column value from last submitted item and then updated currently added list item?

Comment: @GaneshSanap,  read the column value from last submitted item and then updated currently added list item. So let's say the last `reference_number` value is `10132` then, when the user clicks on `add new item` `SharePoint` should `autogenerate` the next `reference_number` which in this would be `10133`. So each time ` add new item` is clicked, the `reference_number` will be autogenerated by adding `1` to previous/last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use power automate flow like below to get the last highest value in `reference_number` column and then update newly created item:

[image]

Use correct "internal name" of your reference number column in "Order By". You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

In "Initialize Variable" action, use expression like:

```
add(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']?[0]?['reference_number'], 1)
```

Then use this variable to update the reference number column using "Update item" action.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still getting the same error at the `initialize variable` step.

Comment: Are there existing list items with value in `reference_number` column? Can you add screenshot of current flow you are using to original question by editing it and the flow expression you are using?

Comment: Yes there are, kindly see the updated question

Comment: Did you use the "Get items" action with descending order on column as shown in answer? And used it's output in initialize variable action?

Comment: Yes I did, please see updated workflow in the question.

Comment: Total how many items are in the list? If you have more than 5000 items, enable pagination from "Get items" action settings. Note: you can get maximum 100000 items using "Get items" action.

Comment: Thank you, what should I enter in `threshold`? Btw total observations are `917`.

Comment: So, I enabled `pagination` and set `threshold` to `5000` but I am still getting the same error.