# auto generate column value whenever a new row is added

Tags: power-automate

I have a list in a SharePoint website that will grow/update as data entries are made.

Purpose: I would like to tell the SharePoint website that whenever a new row is added, auto generate the next column (`Reference Number` (datatype `numeric`)) value based on the previous value which for example is `10822`.

I found a workflow on Google using Power Automate however, I am getting an `invalid expression error`.

Power Automate workflow:

[image]

Expression:

```
add(outputs(`Reference Number`),1)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on your setup.

If this expression is within an apply to each loop you could use:

```
add(item()?['ReferenceNumber'],1)
```

Otherwise it would probably be something like:

```
add(outputs('Name_of_Action')?['ReferenceNumber'], 1)
```

*All these examples assume that your column is of type number. Otherwise you probably also need to add an int() function around the column to be able to add +1*

When the property needs to be retrieved from a trigger action you can use:

```
add(triggerOutputs()?['body/ReferenceNumber'], 1)
```

Comment: In that case it probably is:

`add(triggerOutputs()?['body/ReferenceNumber'], 1)`

Comment: So once I save the workflow, whenever I click on `add new item` on the `SharePoint` website, it will autogenerate the column value in the new row, right? Or do I also need to add `Update Item` to the workflow or anything else?

Comment: What your flow currently does is retrieve the existing value of that column and increment it with 1 in the variable. Nothing is written back to SharePoint unless you tell the flow to do that ;) You would have to use the update item to actually write it back to  the SharePoint item.

Comment: I am getting an error with the expression provided in the edited answer. For more info, kindly look at [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304069/add-flow-expression-to-update-item) question.